How to identify strings in my Pandas dataframe
Let's say I have a dataframe like this:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, np.nan, 2],
     [2, 3, 'I'],
     [3, 4, 'II']],
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df

how do I identify all the strings exclude null values and if it's a roman number, convert it into the integer correspond to this roman number?
I tried this to locate the coordination of string but it includes the null values.
res = np.argwhere(df_pre.values.astype('str'))


argwhere (and where) is only as useful as the condition argument, your df_pre.values.astype('str').  All they do is return the indices of the True/non-zero elements of that argument.

Mixed dtypes will result in an 'object' column, so the first step is to filter on that, then you can just apply a function that checks the type of the value.
I'm going to ignore the requirement to convert Roman numerals to int; that's covered elsewhere, e.g. Converting Roman Numerals to integers in python. In place of a function that does that, I'll use len, which coincidentally gets the right result.
df1 = df.select_dtypes('object').applymap(
    lambda x: len(x) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
df1

   C
0  2
1  1
2  2

You can then insert the columns back, e.g.
df.assign(**df1)

   A    B  C
0  1  NaN  2
1  2  3.0  1
2  3  4.0  2


I would do the map and would use the roman library.
The simple code would be:
import roman

converted_df = df.map(lambda x: roman.fromRoman(x) if type(x) == str else x)

Using lambda function iterates only if the type of the value within the cell is str. The function to use is fromRoman.
You can install roman with pip or your favorite tool.

Thanks for providing this library! It's really useful.

You could map type onto the values and compare to str:
df.map(type) == str

Output:
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1  False  False   True
2  False  False   True

To get the integer indexes:
np.argwhere(df.map(type) == str)

Output:
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 2]], dtype=int64)

As for converting those strings to numbers, there are many good solutions here.

I solved it by doing this:
First step, creating a function that takes in a roman numeral as a string and makes it an integer.
Second step: trying to apply romanToInt to all possible values in the dataframe
# Define the function to convert Roman numerals to integers
def romanToInt(s):
    values = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
    result = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i + 1 < len(s) and values[s[i]] < values[s[i + 1]]:
            result -= values[s[i]]
        else:
            result += values[s[i]]
    return result

# Apply a function element-wise to the entire DataFrame
def convert_value(value):
    if pd.notnull(value) and isinstance(value, str):
        try:
            # Try to make the string an integer
            return romanToInt(value)
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return value

df = df.map(convert_value)

print(df)

   A    B  C
0  1  NaN  2
1  2  3.0  1
2  3  4.0  2


A bare except is bad practice. Instead, use the specific exception you're expecting like except ValueError

Thank you for the advice, edited it to be KeyError
